# Checking presence of item in growing nested list from same list

Tags: python, list, loops, nested, tuples

I have a list that is n size long and has a lists and non-lists on each n. For example given n = to various values then the items on that list could look something like:

```
possible_sub_combinations[3455] = [(A, B), (A, C), "A", "B"]
possible_sub_combinations[3499] = [(A, G), (B, C), "F", "H"]
possible_sub_combinations[6589] = [(B, C), (A, C), "A", "B", "C"]
possible_sub_combinations[9872] = [(A, F), "A", "F", (A, D), "E", (F, H), "G"]
```

I want to flag each list as **OK** or **NOT OK** based on whether the inner list items i.e. (A, B) & (A, C) are in the same list but listed individually not inside another list. My `possible_sub_combinations` lists can grow in size, so some will have as few as 3 inner lists or as many as 20.

So for example an **OK** list would be:

```
[(A, B), (A, C), "A", "B", "C"]
```

Since in both inner lists (A, B) and (A, C) you can find the same letters by themselves.

A **NOT OK** list would be:

```
[(A, B), (A, E), "A", "B", "C"]
```

Since (A, E) contains "E" which is not on that list on its own.

What I have tried so far:

```
for mainsubset in possible_sub_combinations:
    for individuals in mainsubset:
        if isinstance(individuals, tuple):  #Here I check if the component is a tuple or an individual    
            effect1 = individuals[0] #I assign the 1st letter of the inner list
            effect2 = individuals[1] #second letter of the inner list
            flag1 = False
            flag2 = False
            for comparison_individuals in mainsubset: #Loop the value looking for matches on non-list components
                if not isinstance(comparison_individuals, tuple):
                    if effect1 == comparison_individuals:
                        flag1 = True
                    if effect2 == comparison_individuals:
                        flag2 = True
    if flag1 & flag2:
        hierarchical_combinations.append(mainsubset)
```

This kind of works with lists with only 1 inner list but I just cannot make it work on ones that have more than 1. I think I am VERY close but I just spent 8 hours trying to get this to work and I have run out of ideas and have gone crossed-eye.

Also, please be nice. I am learning Python and I probably am making a rookie mistake. But any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the strings that are in tuples and the strings that are solo into sets. Then check if the difference of these is not empty.

```
for mainsubset in possible_sub_combinations:
    tuples = set(sum(x for x in mainsubset if isinstance(x, tuple), ()))
    strings = set(x for x in mainsubset if isinstance(x, str))
    if tuples - strings:
        hierarchical_combinations.append(mainsubset)
```

Comment: This is super clever! Thanks. I was not aware I could subtract lists and get a result. 1 follow up question... I don't need them to be matched. So there can be additional nonlist items that are not within list items and that is ok. So instead of looking for an empty result from the subtraction I would look for a greater than? Since I could potentially have more string items than tuples if any.

Comment: You can't subtract lists. That's why I converted them to sets first.

Comment: Ok. I got my head around the code all except for the part of the 'sum'. Why do you need to sum that list before converting to set?

Comment: @chepox I'm using that to flatten the list of tuples. `('A', 'B') + ('B', 'C') => ('A', 'B', 'B', 'C')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all`:

```
def is_ok(d):
  return all(all(j in d for j in i) for i in d if isinstance(i, tuple))

vals = [[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), 'A', 'B', 'C'], [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'E'), 'A', 'B', 'C'], [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), 'A', 'B'], [('A', 'G'), ('B', 'C'), 'F', 'H'], [('B', 'C'), ('A', 'C'), 'A', 'B', 'C'], [('A', 'F'), 'A', 'F', ('A', 'D'), 'E', ('F', 'H'), 'G']]
result = ['ok' if is_ok(i) else 'not ok' for i in vals]
```

Output:

```
['ok', 'not ok', 'not ok', 'not ok', 'ok', 'not ok']
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems it would work very well. I am accepting Barmar's answer just because it applies a little better to what I already have. Nonetheless, thank you very much for your contribution.